Recycling unused components
Can unused individual components such as resistors, capacitors, diodes, transistors, integrated circuits, etc.... be recycled (in the US)? Or should they just be thrown in the trash if they won't be used by anyone?
I have many from leftover assemblies. I keep anything that I think I might be able to use in the future, but many are too small for me to solder by hand anyway.

In the volumes that we are handling as engineers/ prototypers/ developers/ hobbyists I think we can just throw them in the trash.

In general, most passive components don't have enough intrinsic value to justify putting effort into recycling them.  But a local radio club or maker group would love to add them to their stock of parts.

Try not to throw really old parts into the general waste stream, especially if you suspect or know that they contain lead, cadmium or mercury. Some places may accept components as e-waste, with exemptions (as in  not charging or not requiring you to go to a for-profit company) for 'household' or 'small business' residents, but it might be a can of worms you don't want to open. It seems very dependent on where you live.

In general, I would recommend going to someone who can reliably recycle them as the components contains chemicals that can be harmful for environment. I would recommend going to an offical website by searching 'E-waste disposla'.
